# Why should a single method interface be tagged @FunctionalInterface?

Tags: java, lambda, sonarqube, functional-interface

SonarQube gives me a bunch of [Squid:S1909 @FunctionalInterface annotation should be used to flag Single Abstract Method interface](https://dev.eclipse.org/sonar/rules/show/squid:S1609) warnings.

The explanation is not too great. It mentions breaking existing lamda expressions, but wouldn't the compiler already catch if I add a new method to the interface and break existing lambdas? Is the annotation mainly about intention revealing here?

If the code is not used in lambda expressions (it isn't because it's from a legacy code base where only some interfaces are used in lambdas) --- is there any point in adding `@FunctionalInterface`?

Comment: This is more for you. The code that uses the interface might not be compiled together with it. So you won't necessarily know what you break when you make the change (new method) without `@FunctionalInterface`.